# Corrupt MBR in RAID-0 setup - Missing Operating System

Tags: windows-7, mbr, raid-0

I have a 2x500GB RAID-0 setup on an Asus M4A785TD-V EVO Motherboard.
Recently, I was doing regular cleaning and after assembling up again the PC started normal.

But on the next boot, it suddenly gave me a "Missing Operating System" error at boot.
The recovery disk is not able to detect an OS on the disk. In fact no presence of RAID is being detected.

Is there any way to bring back the RAID configuration without getting rid of the data and going in for a full format?

**Additional Problem:**
In the BIOS, I am seeing both HDDs. But in the windows setup is is detecting only one HDD - that too unformatted.

Comment: The windows install should only see one drive in a RAID 0 that's normal does it show it as 1TB?.

Comment: no, it shows up as 500GB

Comment: Did you set the RAID up in a raid controller after bios or in windows?

Comment: The RAID setup was done in the BIOS - and the RAID drivers were loaded during windows installation to detect the combined 1TB block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth running a check on the disk's to verify they are without errors, there's lots of [tools on the Hiren boot CD](http://www.hiren.info) for this.

You are using Hardware RAID (setup in BIOS). [Here](http://www.techspot.com/vb/post98249-3.html) is a great post about 'repairing' a damaged RAID 0 setup from a [thread](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic14076.html) with lots of other useful information.

Depending on your RAID controller, there might be some repair software you can run. Check the manufacturors website for more info. [Highpoint](http://www.highpoint-tech.com), [Adaptec](http://www.adaptec.com) etc

Comment: Replied to stephen above, and I'll also check on the disks with HirenBCD and UBCD.

Comment: Great news! Well done and thanks for updating us (and the points!) :)